# Apache document root defined in config not being used

Tags: linux, apache-http-server

I'm quickly running out of ideas on how to resolve this issue. I hope I've provided enough information, but if I've missed anything, please let me know.

While I do not have multiple domains right now, I want the ability to have another virtual host on my apache server in the future, so I want my file structure to look like this:

```
/var/www/
    |myname
        |index.html
    |coolwebsitethatdoesntexistyet
        |index.html
```

as of right now, only myname.com is a thing (my actual name is a pain to spell)

**Apache defaults to serving the files at `/var/www/html/index.html`, but I wanted to serve `/var/www/myname/index.html`**

so the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`  file looks like this:

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/myname"
    ServerName myname.com
    ServerAlias www.myname.com
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    <Directory "/var/www/myname">
        AllowOverride All
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        Require all granted
        Order allow,deny
        # Any other directives
    </Directory>
    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

**Even with changing apache2.conf (and restarting apache), myname.com still points to the stuff under   `var/www/html/index.html`**

If I'm correct, I believe that the `000-default.conf` will be used if there's nothing at `apache2.conf.`

so I edited `000-default.conf` to have the same thing that was at `apache2.conf` to see if it worked then. It didn't.

for more information here is the output for `grep -r DocumentRoot /etc`

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf: DocumentRoot /var/www/myname
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf: DocumentRoot /var/www/ht                                                                                                                                                             ml
/etc/apache2/sites-available/myname.com.conf: DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myname.com/public_html
/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf: DocumentRoot "/var/www/myname"
```

The output for  `sudo apache2ctl -S`

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server myname.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:2)
         port 80 namevhost myname.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:2)
                 alias www.myname.com
         port 80 namevhost myname.com (/etc/apache2/apache2.conf:219)
                 alias www.myname.com
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

TLDR: **Read the Bold**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you delete your browser cache? Since it's a static file, the browser most certainly has cached it. Try deleting or even disabling your cache, or opening an incognito window - then try opening the webpage again.

Comment: I have already done that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR I read the part in bold but these are my suggestions anyway.**

> I want my file structure to look like this:

```
/var/www/
    |myname
        |index.html
    |coolwebsitethatdoesntexistyet
        |index.html
```

I would suggest configuring Apache similar to the following:

- Under `apache2.conf`, set your `ServerName` to a host name *other* than e.g `mysite.com`. This doesn't have to be a reachable host name (i.e. you can use something as simple as ex. `Sam` or `Neo`). Set your `DocumentRoot` to `/var/www`. You can drop an `index.html` file in there as necessary.
- Under `000-default.conf`, set your `ServerName` to `mysite.com`. Set your `DocumentRoot` to `/var/www/myname`.
- If you want a second virtual host, create a new one under `sites-available` and give it a unique `ServerName` (ex. `coolwebsite.com`) and the proper `DocumentRoot` (ex. `/var/www/coolwebsitethatdoesntexistyet`).

***Well, obviously...***

- Restart Apache after making any changes to any `.conf` file(s).
- Don't forget to enable your second site if you wish to test it.
- Any site name that doesn't have a DNS entry associated with it (e.g. `coolsite.com`) needs to be added to your `hosts` file for testing purposes.

**Notes**

- If you want to be extra safe about directory permissions, try `var/www/html` for `apache2.conf` along with `/var/www/html/myname` and `/var/www/html/coolwebsitethatdoesntexistyet` for your virtual hosts, even if this is just for testing.
- Even if this doesn't work, this configuration should arguably eliminate any simple issues with Apache.